# CMake OpenCV installation issue

Tags: software-installation, compiling, opencv, cmake

This is driving me nuts for the past three hours. I *simply* want to install CMake and then install OpenCV 3.1, but I am getting an `Unsupported protocol` error (please see below).

I installed CMake 3.4.3. like this:

```
wget https://cmake.org/files/v3.4/cmake-3.4.3.tar.gz
tar xf cmake-3.4.3.tar.gz
cd cmake-3.4.3
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Then ran this:

```
./bootstrap --prefix=/usr
make
sudo make install
```

It goes wrong when I run this command in the installation process for OpenCV:

`cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local ..`

This is the exact error I am getting:

```
CMake Warning at 3rdparty/ippicv/downloader.cmake:56 (message):
  ICV: Local copy of ICV package has invalid MD5 hash:
  d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e (expected:
  808b791a6eac9ed78d32a7666804320e)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  3rdparty/ippicv/downloader.cmake:110 (_icv_downloader)
  cmake/OpenCVFindIPP.cmake:237 (include)
  cmake/OpenCVFindLibsPerf.cmake:12 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:537 (include)


-- ICV: Downloading ippicv_linux_20151201.tgz...
CMake Error at 3rdparty/ippicv/downloader.cmake:73 (file):
  file DOWNLOAD HASH mismatch

    for file: [/home/ao/opt/opencv/3rdparty/ippicv/downloads/linux-808b791a6eac9ed78d32a7666804320e/ippicv_linux_20151201.tgz]
      expected hash: [808b791a6eac9ed78d32a7666804320e]
        actual hash: [d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e]
             status: [1;"Unsupported protocol"]

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  3rdparty/ippicv/downloader.cmake:110 (_icv_downloader)
  cmake/OpenCVFindIPP.cmake:237 (include)
  cmake/OpenCVFindLibsPerf.cmake:12 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:537 (include)


CMake Error at 3rdparty/ippicv/downloader.cmake:77 (message):
  ICV: Failed to download ICV package: ippicv_linux_20151201.tgz.
  Status=1;"Unsupported protocol"
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  3rdparty/ippicv/downloader.cmake:110 (_icv_downloader)
  cmake/OpenCVFindIPP.cmake:237 (include)
  cmake/OpenCVFindLibsPerf.cmake:12 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:537 (include)
```

So apparently theres is a hash mismatch. I am guessing this is a CMake thing (perhaps my installation is not correct?). How must I fix this, it can't possibly be that hard to install OpenCV, right?

Comment: Why not take OpenCV and/or CMake from Ubuntu's package repositories?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the solution in this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31636496/4882455). Basically I just had to manually download the file `ippicv_linux_20151201.tgz` (from [here](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/general/opencv.html)) and move the zip file to the correct location (`/home/ao/opt/opencv/3rdparty/ippicv/downloads/linux-808b791a6eac9ed78d32a7666804320e/`).

Then it could compile :)

Comment: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/5973 - For future reference for 2015 files of ippicv

Answer (score 2):

or, you could recompile cmake with SSL support, because ultimately THAT is the reason for the "hash mismatch" (status: [1;"Unsupported protocol"])

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend to [edit] this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on AskUbuntu.)

Answer (score 1):

From :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32749454/opencv-installation-error-ubuntu-14-04/38054298#38054298

try again with :

```
 cmake \
 -DOPENCV_ICV_URL="http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/opencvlibrary/3rdparty/ippicv"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily disable IPP option if you are sure you don't want to use this third party utility.

```
-DWITH_IPP=OFF
```